# When to delete file shared with external apps by content provider

Tags: android, security, share, android-contentprovider

In my application I allow users to share files with external apps by using content provider. My files are encrypted so before I can share one of those files, I need to decrypt it and store it in application internal storage. After that I implemented custom content provider that can point to the file by using a given URL and return ParcelFileDescriptor instance.

For security issues I would like to remove the file from internal storage after external application has used it, or user canceled operation.

EDIT: The external application that I am sharing file with is a 3rd party application.

So my question is:
When should I remove the file, or do you know of any event that I can listen to or a handler that I can attach to the file?

Thank you for all you responses.

Side question would be:
Do you know of a way where I wouldn't have to store the file on internal storage, but rather send it directly as a stream to the external app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is to use pipes ParcelFileDescriptor.

Code is described in The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development from CommonsWare.

The solution is based on:
https://github.com/nandeeshwar/Pfd-Create-Pipe

Actual solution that I managed to implement is:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe

Answer (score 0):

If it is *your* external application, you could leave an encrypted file and pass the key in an Intent. If it is a 3-rd party external application, you have to find out what that application can accept.

You might also read about services -- maybe they provide what you want.

As to "when", I'd suggest launching a clean-up task in onResume(). (Unless you decide to use a service.)

Comment: Sorry edited my question. So the external application is a 3rd party application. 

The problem with cleaning up onResume is that as I have tested, external application asks for the file only when the operation is finished. So for example in email application when the file is used as an attachment, the external application asks for the file only when the email is sent.